# Regex for specific text

Tags: regex

I am totally new with regex expression and look for a very easy expression to get the the CP Number out of the string below:

sdfdsf | Team Jan-Feb 2022 | KeyD | CP-01602233 | H | Prio

Expected Result = CP= 01602233

THX for your help in advance

Comment: An easy expression based solely on the data in your question would be `/| CP-(\d{8}) |/`. However, since we don't know enough about your data, we can't tell if those numbers might not be always 8 digits exactly, or if other parts of text might match this as well.

Comment: please explain the logic you want to be catched by the regex. A single example is not enough

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex string which searches for CD- follows but a number of any length, not containing a decimal point.

```
CP-\d*
```

if the number could contain a decimal point then use

```
CP-[0-9\.]*
```